# How do I add a subtitle for menu items in Nice menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm using the *Nice menu* module. I need to show a subtitle for each menu item.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu) module

> "Maximize your main navigation by adding text, images, videos,
>   slideshow, tabs, menu blocks, user info ..."
>
> That is now possible by using OM Maximenu which can create menus with
>   all other module blocks you want as attachments, modules like views,
>   slideshow, menu, user, nice menus, quicktabs, and custom blocks with
>   tables, lists, images, videos, etc.

Here a great list of menu [7 Mega Menu modules for Drupal](http://megadrupal.com/blog/7-mega-menu-modules-for-drupal)